# How to find the value of the function f(5,2)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The function definition is f(x,y) = x + f(x-1, x-y). f(1,0) = 5. My job is to find f(5,2). Im not sure if i solved the problem correctly, please correct if so.

1. f(1,0) = 1 + f(0,1) = 5
2. f(0,1) = (has to be) 3 + y
   So:
3. f(5,2) = 5 + 3 + 2 = 10

Comment: I don't understand points 2. and 3.

Comment: @peterwhy if 1 + f(0,1) = 5, and x = 0 if inputed into f than there is no other possibility than f(0,1) to be 3 + y so that 1+ f(0,1) = 5. Does this makes sense or am i misunderstanding something fundamentaly?

Comment: From line $1$ you have $f(0,1)=4,$ not $3$.  In line $2$ you assume it is $3+y$ but you are not given that.

Comment: @Christian If you put $x=0, y=1$ into $f(x,y) = x+f(x-1,x-y)$, you get $f(0,1) = 0+f(-1,-1)$. Nowhere does it say $3+y$.

Comment: @peterwhy my x = 1 and my y= 0, because f(x-1,x-y)->f(1-1,1-0)=f(0,1). But never mind i understand where my mistake lies. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x,y) = x + f(x-1, x-y)$$

if given $f(1,0) = 5$.

$$f(5,2)=5+f(4,3)=5+4+f(3,1)=5+4+3+f(2,2)=5+4+3+2+f(1,0)=14+5=19$$